# AWS CLI Can List S3 Bucket But Access Denied For Python Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, terraform

I've used terraform to setup infra for an s3 bucket and my containerised lambda. I want to trigger the lambda to list the items in my s3 bucket. When I run the aws cli it's fine:

```
aws s3 ls
```

returns

```
2022-11-08 23:04:19 bucket-name
```

This is my lambda:

```
import logging
import boto3

LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)
LOGGER.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    LOGGER.info('Executing function...')
    bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket-name')
    total_objects = 0
    for i in bucket.objects.all():
        total_objects = total_objects + 1
    return {'total_objects': total_objects}
```

When I run the test in the AWS console, I'm getting this:

```
[ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied
```

No idea why this is happening. These are my terraform lambda policies, roles and the s3 setup:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "statements_bucket" {
  bucket = "bucket-name"
  acl    = "private"
}

resource "aws_s3_object" "object" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.statements_bucket.id
  key    = "excel/"
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda" {
  name               = "${local.prefix}-lambda-role"
  path               = "/"
  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
       {
           "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
           "Principal": {
               "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
           },
           "Effect": "Allow"
       }
   ]
}
 EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "lambda" {
  name        = "${local.prefix}-lambda-policy"
  description = "S3 specified access"
  policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
    EOF
}
```

Comment: `aws s3 ls` doesn't list items (actually 'objects') in your buckets. It lists your buckets.

Comment: If you use the Lambda console to view the permissions for this Lambda function, does it include your Allow statement for `s3:ListBucket` on `arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name`?

Comment: I've just looked at this. It hasn't got any policy statements... why would that be?

Comment: Did you actually [attach](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role_policy_attachment) the IAM policy to the IAM role for the Lambda function? Your Terraform template above is incomplete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, your Lambda function has the correct IAM role (the one indicated in your Terraform template) but that IAM role has no attached policies.

You need to attach the S3 policy, and any other IAM policies needed, to the IAM role. For example:

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "lambda-attach" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.role.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.policy.arn
}
```

Comment: Thanks @jarmod that was what I was missing!

Answer (score 2):

In order to run `aws s3 ls`, you would need to authorize the action `s3:ListAllMyBuckets`. This is because `aws s3 ls` lists *all* of your buckets.

You should be able to list the *contents* of your bucket using `aws s3 ls s3://bucket-name`. <s>However, you're probably going to have to add `"arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"` to the resource list for your role as well.</s> Edit: nevermind!

Comment: You don't need the object-level resource `arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*` to list the objects in the bucket.

Comment: @dawaltco I added the `"arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"` to the resource list for my role but it didn't work. Also, `aws s3 ls s3://bucket-name` DOES list the contents of the buckets, so I'm none the wiser...

Comment: @clattenburgcake what does being able to run `aws s3 ls s3://bucket-name` (is this on your laptop?) have to do with the code running in your Lambda function?

Comment: @jarmod Just as a proof that I can access the objects in the bucket I guess. Unless I'm thinking about this the wrong way